# User Roles Not Getting Updated

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am facing a issue in Sitecore UI when I am editing an existing user to add/delete **'User Roles'** under the **'Member Of'** tab, its not getting updated. However, when I am adding a **New User** and assigning the User Roles, then it shows up correct. Any idea whats causing this issue/Or anyone else faced the same?

This issue is also referenced by some other person [here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?postid=47611).
I attached an image for more reference!

Tried looking up online but in vain, hope someone can assist me on this. Thanks in advance![image: Refer to this image for further reference.]

EDIT: Step by step of what I am doing:

[image: Selecting the user]
[image: Clicking on the edit button]
[image: Adding 'Marketing Designer' User Roles to that particular user]
[image: Its shows that Marketing Designer is added, I clicked 'OK' after this. No popup confirmation.]
[image: Clicked on that User again and edit: Marketing Designer is NOT added.]

Hope this illustrate the problem much better!

Comment: Does the Sitecore log have any related entries?

Comment: @OptimizedQuery: Where I can look the log file?

Comment: `\Data\logs` or via the log viewer.  From the desktop view, `Start -> Reporting Tools -> Log Viewer`.

Comment: @OptimizedQuery: Much appreciated! I viewed the file, no entries regarding Roles.

Comment: Are other properties of the user saved properly?

Comment: Are you using the out-of-the-box Role provider?  Or a custom system?

Comment: @MarasMusielak: Nope, none for the 'User Roles', but if I am changing the 'Domains' -Sitecore, Default, Extranet , it saves properly.

Comment: @Bryan: I am using whatever Sitecore has: Security Tools -> User Manager.

Comment: Looks like a good candidate to contact Sitecore customer service...

Comment: @All: Thank you for all your response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and it turned out to be solved by ensuring the App_Browsers folder was in the root of the website.  When this was not there, several dialogs would not save correctly (User Roles, Security Assignment to items)

Comment: Ah! I located the file and inside the App_Browsers 2 files were missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem but Jay S's solution didnt work for me. I'm using Sitecore 7.2

The problem is you can't add roles to the user, but what you can do is add users to the role.

The workaround is to go to the Role Manager, then click on Members and select the users to add in to the role.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem in one of the **Sitecore** versions with a role selector window which wasn't big enough, so the buttons `Cancel` and `Ok` were hidden. I was able to select roles, but then I wasn't able to confirm my selection unless I extended the window size:

[image: sitecore - edit roles]

You've provided a screenshot for the **Edit User** popup but not the one which is displayed afer you click `Edit` on this screen so I don't know if this is the reason of your issue as well.

Comment: Please see my edit, I added more images to illustrate the issue more better.